# Can you recommend a good shop to get spices from in Derby?

Tags: spices

Can anyone recommend a good spice shop in Derby / Nottingham?
I am after some Allspice berries, I've seen some online but I just wondered if there was anywhere local I can go and get them.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about specialty knowledge of a small geographic region, better suited to local business directories or phone books.


Comment: This is absolutely begging for a meta question. (Too localized was *explicitly removed* as a close reason, and I have no idea whether to interpret that as SE saying this kind of question is generally okay or just saying that we need to come up with another rationalization...)

Comment: I almost want to say it's a shopping question, where the "product" is a store.

Comment: I think this goes back to our never-fully-at-concensus question on sourcing:  http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1292/what-types-of-sourcing-questions-should-be-allowed-revisit-march-2013-plea

Comment: @Jefromi: One important difference between this question and the subject matter discussed on meta/MSO is that this isn't asking how to find a specific ingredient, but rather a very *broad category* of ingredients. *Lots* of stores sell spices including most grocery stores, so in effect, it's actually searching for a specific *type of store* which is better served by sites like Yelp/Google Places, local forums, etc. So I vote in favour of off-topic. If there was a specific hard-to-find spice being asked about here, I would have left it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend of mine from Nottingham buys a lot of exotic ingredients/spices in [Pak Foods](http://www.pakfoods.net/) market, and I searched a little and saw you have one in Derby too ([here is a link with a review](http://www.yelp.co.uk/biz/pak-foodstore-derby?utm_campaign=qype_uk&utm_source=google)). But probably [many asian](http://www.chungwahderby.com/)/international markets will cary a large variety of spices. Also, allspice is not super exotic to English cuisine, so you might find it in better stocked supermarkets (like [Waitrose](http://www.waitrose.com/shop/ProductView-10317-10001-3421-Bart+allspice), Sainsbury's or a big [Tesco](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&authuser=0&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1093&bih=516&q=tesco+allspice) for example).

Anyway, when we were living in the UK we ordered stuff from [Steenbergs](http://www.steenbergs.co.uk/) most of the time (and most of my friend also get spices from them) - the quality of their spices is just astonishing (much better than anything I found in most stores). I still order stuff from them to my friends house and pick it up when I visit =)